# How to view remote repo's lastest several commit hash using git?

Tags: git

I want to check commit progress between the remote and the locale and don't want to open the repo url in browser.

In some case, I want to watch repo's dev branch's lastest 3 commit hash and their commit detail.Can git do it?

Command should be like

`git log remote origin dev --depth 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what's happening on the remote, you'll want to `fetch` the latest commits. This will let you keep your local branch and the remote branch's history separate.

```
$ git fetch origin
```

Logging will show you the last three commits on you the branch you're interested in:

```
$ git log origin/dev -n 3
```